# Unable to cmake mysql for ARM

Tags: mysql, cmake, centos7, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build MySQL client for CentOS7 - (aarch64) by using this guide: [Building MySQL from Source](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-sourcebuild-excerpt-5.7-en.pdf#page=7&zoom=100,72,96).

On this step `$> rpmbuild --rebuild --clean MySQL-VERSION.src.rpm` towards the end of the command I get the following error;

```
  [ 82%] Built target mysqlpump_lib
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/mysql-5.7.39/debug'
make[1]: *** [libmysqld/CMakeFiles/sql_embedded.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/mysql-5.7.39/debug'
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.MolOTB (%build)


RPM build errors:
    mysql-community-5.7.39-1.el7.src.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3a79bd29: NOKEY
    user pb2user does not exist - using root
    group common does not exist - using root
    user pb2user does not exist - using root
    group common does not exist - using root
    user pb2user does not exist - using root
    group common does not exist - using root
    user pb2user does not exist - using root
    group common does not exist - using root
    user pb2user does not exist - using root
    group common does not exist - using root
    user pb2user does not exist - using root
    group common does not exist - using root
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.MolOTB (%build)
```

What could be causing this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The **actual error message** is somewhere **above** the lines you show. Please, include that message into the question post. Exactly that message should be used when debug problems. The messages like `make: *** [all] Error 2` and `make[1]: *** [libmysqld/CMakeFiles/sql_embedded.dir/all] Error 2` are nearly useless.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Thanks! It was the gnu compiler I've used. It was 4.5 now I've upgraded it to 7.3 + and it went through until the latest error I just saw.

Comment: It is nice that you have found the actual error message. But again: **add** it to the **question post**. On Stack Overflow we expect every question post to be useful for **future readers**, who could find their problems to be similar to yours one. But without the error message it is impossible to match your problem with other one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Okay I will add the whole output. I must have been confused because of throwing out all the warning and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay!

I was able to move forward with by installing newer gnu compiler.

```
[root@2e509877c7be mysql]# gcc --version
```

gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[root@2e509877c7be mysql]#